# Storyboard get messed when working in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode7, swift3, xcode8

I am migrating from `Xcode7` to `Xcode8` and found issue in `storybroad`. I am not using `auto layout` so when ever I open `storyboard` even after adjusting frame I found my whole `UI` messed up again and this happens again and again whenever I open `Xcode8`.

#### View in Xcode7.3.1

[image: Xcode 7.3.1]

#### View in Xcode8

[image: Xcode 8]

in `Xcode8` frame size and origin is disturbed.

### 1)Is there any work around?

### 2)Do i have to go for `autolayout`?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: While this comment will not address your issue in anyway, I feel the need to point out that you most definitely **should** be using autoLayout. There is a lot of work involved in handling all screen sizes / resolutions. AutoLayout handles this for you

Comment: Interface Builder in Xcode 8 has many bad bugs. I glad I don't have to use it most of the times.

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin thanks for the reply. i don't have option then to shift to autolayout??

Comment: @dasdom do i have have to downgrade Xcode and then work on autolayout

Comment: No, I would do all the layout in code.

Comment: @dasdom dealing manually with frames etc? you can't be serious. Stackviews and autolayout are tremendous time savers once you get to grips with them

Comment: No, I mean do all the layout in code. Of course with Auto Layout and StackViews.

Answer (score 2):

There is workaround if you are using autolayout! Select individual `ViewController` from storyboard and from `Resolve Autolayout issues` press `updates frames` under `All views in your view controller`.

You can refer screenshot below,

[image]

or you can try by changing `Simulated Size` of your `view controller` from `size inspector` to `fixed size` or you can try to change `simulated metrics` from `attribute inspector`

Answer (score -2):

This is the issue in Xcode 8.0, which is resolved in Xcode 8.1.

Thanks.